# ModelChoiceField gives an invalid choice error upon form submission

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to allow the user to delete a list of associated foreignkeys to a particular model.

Say we have these two models:

```
class IceBox(models.Model):
    ...

class FoodItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    icebox = models.ForeignKey(IceBox)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

The form used to select multiple fooditems to be deleted:

```
class IceBoxEditForm(forms.Form):
        fooditems = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FoodItem.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), empty_label=None)
```

The corresponding view:

```
def icebox_edit(request, item=None):
        # Grab the particular icebox
        icebox = get_object_or_404(IceBox, pk=item)

        if request.method == "POST":
                form = IceBoxEditForm(request.POST)
                print request.POST
                if form.is_valid():
                        # Delete should happen
        else:
                form = IceBoxEditForm()
                # Only use the list of fooditems that this icebox holds
                form.fields['fooditems'].queryset = icebox.fooditem_set.all()

        return render_to_response('icebox_edit.html', {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The form correctly lists checkboxes of the fooditems associated with that icebox. However, when I select something and then submit the form, I'll get the form error:

**`Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`**

Is there some other custom validation I'm missing that Django expects?

**EDIT:** I have tried this, but it gives a syntax error:

```
form:
class IceBoxEditForm(forms.Form):
        fooditems = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=FoodItem.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), empty_label=None)


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
              queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset', None)
              super(IceBoxEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

              if queryset:
                        self.fields['fooditems'].queryset = queryset

view:
        form = IceBoxEditForm(queryset=icebox.fooditem_set.all(), request.POST) # Syntax error!

        ....
    else:
        form = IceBoxEditForm(queryset=icebox.fooditem_set.all())
        ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've changed the queryset for the field for a GET request, but not for a POST. So when you submit the form, Django is still using the original queryset, so your selection is not valid.

Either change it at the beginning of the view, so it happens for both POST and GET, or even better do it in the form's `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code to reflect your comment. However, I still receive the same error.

Comment: I guess to clarify, how would I now pass the 'queryset' to the form for POST? Doing `form = IceBoxEditForm(queryset=icebox.fooditem_set.all(), request.POST)` gives a syntax error.

Comment: You must always pass positional arguments before keyword args. `form = MyForm(request.POST, queryset=myqueryset)` is what you want.