# Django form with custom init for ModelChoiceField failing validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm having strange behavior with a form ModelChoiceField.  A little background.  I need a form that has a variable queryset for a certain field.  Looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clean-met/1057640#1057640) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788777/modelchoicefield-gives-an-invalid-choice-error-upon-form-submission), I have created an init method for my form to handle this based on the request passed in to the init method.

```
class QueryTimeEntryForm(forms.Form):
query_start_date = forms.DateField(label='Start Date:', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(), input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d'])
query_end_date = forms.DateField(label='End Date:', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(), input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y', '%Y-%m-%d'])
time_query_unit = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Unit.objects.all().order_by('unit'), label='', required=False, empty_label='Choose a unit', widget=forms.Select())
time_query_employee = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employee.objects.none(), label='', required=False, empty_label='Choose an employee', widget=forms.Select())
time_query_radio = forms.ChoiceField(label='', widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'queryRadio'}), choices=QUERY_CHOICES, initial='1')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super (QueryTimeEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #depending on the user, set the queryset of the employee drop down
    #get the employee category for the user
    today = datetime.today()
    emp = Employee.objects.filter(user__exact=self.request.user)
    ec = EmployeeCategory.objects.filter(employee__exact=emp[0]).filter(effectiveDate__lte=today).filter(Q(enddate__gte=today) | Q(enddate__isnull=True))[0]

    if ec.category.category == 1:
        self.fields['time_query_employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(user__exact=self.request.user)
    elif ec.category.category == 2:
        #get the unit for this category 2 employee
        unit = EmployeeUnit.objects.filter(employee__exact=emp).filter(effective_date__lte=today).filter(Q(end_date__gte=today) | Q(end_date__isnull=True))[0].unit
        #get the employees who currently share the unit with the current category 2 employee, excluding the current category 2 employee
        self.fields['time_query_employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(employee_for_employeeunit__unit__exact=unit).filter(Q(employee_for_employeeunit__end_date__gte=today) | Q(employee_for_employeeunit__end_date__isnull=True)).exclude(employee_for_employeeunit__exact=emp).order_by('user__first_name')
    else:
        #get category 1
        cat = Category.objects.filter(category__exact=1)[0]
        self.fields['time_query_employee'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(employee_for_employeecategory__category__exact=cat).filter(Q(employee_for_employeecategory__enddate__gte=today) | Q(employee_for_employeecategory__enddate__isnull=True)).order_by('user__first_name')
```

When the form isn't bound, everything works just fine.  I get just the Employees I expect in the drop down in the html.  The problem I'm having is that when posting the form, the ModelChoiceField fails validation.  As I step through, I notice that similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788777/modelchoicefield-gives-an-invalid-choice-error-upon-form-submission), I'm getting the "Select a valid choice" error, probably because the queryset is Employees.objects.none() when super is called and the validation occurs.  Should I clear all the errors and redo a full_clean after setting the queryset, or should I take a different approach?  Basically I'm stuck, not understanding exactly what's going on, nor where to go from here.  Everything was working fine before I added the init method and had a standard Employee queryset, so it must be something I'm doing with that.

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to test all three of your category branches?  Personally I would probably insert a pdb.set_trace() call at the beginning of the `__init__` call, run it using the Django development server, and see what happens when I post the form.

As a readability tip - you can omit `__exact`, and you can replace your filter(Q() | Q()) calls here with a .exclude making the inverse comparison, since null values will never be true.  That is, instead of your original:

```
unit = EmployeeUnit.objects.filter(employee__exact=emp).filter(effective_date__lte=today).filter(Q(end_date__gte=today) | Q(end_date__isnull=True))[0].unit
```

you can write:

```
unit = EmployeeUnit.objects.filter(employee=emp, effective_date__lte=today).exclude(end_date__lt=today)[0].unit
```

Comment: Thanks for the readability tip.  Today it's working.  I don't have a clue as to why it was failing yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

@Shawn, I encountered this same issue today.  I noticed when debugging (in Eclipse, with the Variables pane shown/active) the form's `__init__`() method and line-stepping through the code that I'd get the "Select a valid choice" error.  However, if I clear my breakpoints and just let it run, or if I line-step debug with the Variables pane not shown/not active, then I don't get the error.  Something with the rendering of the variables in Eclipse results in the error.