# Handling POST request when using ModelChoiceView

Tags: django, django-forms

My simple form looks like this:

```
class PropertyFilterForm(forms.Form):
    property_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Property.objects.values_list('type', flat=True).order_by().distinct())
```

`property_type` returns a flat list of String values to the drop-down list in my template.

Now, when i choose one of the values and hit "Submit" - i get the following error:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
>   choices.

My view at the moment looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PropertyFilterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            selected_type = form.cleaned_data['property_type']
            properties = Property.objects.filter(type=selected_type)
    else:
        form = PropertyFilterForm()
        properties = Property.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',  context=locals())
```

I read and re-read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788777/modelchoicefield-gives-an-invalid-choice-error-upon-form-submission) many times. It seems to be the same thing, but still I wasn't able to figure out the exact solution.

What I understood so far, is that I need to either explicitly specify a queryset for my form each time I call it in the view, or (better) specify the queryset in the init method of my form.

Could please someone elaborate on whether we need to specify a queryset the way i described above?

If yes, why? Haven't we already specified it in the form definition?

I would be really grateful for any code snippets

Comment: A model choice field should use a regular queryset. As far as I know, it's not possible to use `values()` with it. If you want to select a string instead of a `Property` instance, then you should use a regular choice field. You'll need to construct the choices in the `__init__` method.

Comment: That was my initial intention, but the top -answerer for django Daniel Roseman said that i still should roll with the ModelChoiceField.   But I'll keep it in mind and will try out the regular choice field. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, also i had really hard time specifying the default initial value for my ChoiceField. I didn't manage it :(

Comment: I saw that Daniel recommeded using `ModelChoiceField` on your other question, but I'm not sure I agree with him in this case. I've added an answer that uses `ChoiceField` below. If you have problems setting `initial`, you'll need to give more details.

Comment: I don't think that the [question you linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788777/modelchoicefield-gives-an-invalid-choice-error-upon-form-submission) is particularly similar to your use case. That user had problems because they were dynamically changing the queryset. You don't usually have to do that with a model choice field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the user to select a string, not a property instance, so I think it would be a better fit to use a `ChoiceField` instead of a `ModelChoiceField`.

```
class PropertyFilterForm(forms.Form):
    property_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertyFilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['property_type'].choices = Property.objects.values_list('type', 'type').order_by('type').distinct()
```

The disadvantage of using a `ChoiceField` is we need to generate the choices in the `__init__` method of the form. We have lost the nice functionality of the `ModelChoiceField`, where the queryset is evaluated every time the form is created.

It's not clear to me why Daniel recommended sticking with `ModelChoiceField` rather than `ChoiceField`. If you were to use `ModelChoiceField`, I think you'd have to subclass it and override `label_from_instance`. As far as I know, using `values()` is not going to work.

To specify the initial value, you can either hardcode it in the form definition,

```
class PropertyFilterForm(forms.Form):
    property_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], initial='initial_type')
```

or set it in the `__init__` method,

```
self.fields['property_type'].initial = 'initial_type'
```

or provide it when instantiating the form:

```
    form = PropertyFilterForm(request.POST, initial={'property_type': 'initial_type'})
```

Comment: I have just tried this approach and it works fine, thanks! BUT :) There are two things without which this whole thing is not complete. 1. How do i specify an initial value displayed in the drop-down? (specifying an init argument didn't help)  2. How do i get the current value displayed in the dropbox the first time the page is loaded (the GET request)?

Comment: Unfortunately none of the three proposed methods changes the initial value displayed in the drop-down list. Am i doing/understanding something wrong?

Comment: Oh!! I think i know what's wrong :) I've been trying to specify the initial value that is not in the choices list. The initial value should be in that list, right?

Comment: Yes, the initial value should be a valid choice.